# Replacement for document.write but with append function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to now is there any function like document.write() on JavaScript but instead of replacing element it append them because I build a function for replacing user input with codes and it work but the problem is instead of adding codes on specific place but he replace the all page content.

My functions code.

```
function one(json) {
        var j = 0;
        var img = new Array();
        var maxpost=json.feed.entry.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < numposts1; i++) {
            var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
            var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
            var pcm;
            var posturl;
            var postAuthor = entry.author[0].name.$t;
            var postLabels = entry.category[1].term;

if ((i>0)&&(i<maxpost)) {
var trtd = '<a href="'+posturl+'">'+posttitle+'</a><h2>'+posttitle+'</h2>     <span>'+postAuthor+'</span><span>'+postLabels+'</span><div>'+img[i]+'</div>'; 
document.write(trtd);
}
            j++;
        }
    }
```

and this is the second part of code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.widget-content').each(function(){
var b = $(this).html();
    var a = b.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
var code = $('#myscript').attr('src');
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.src=code;
$('.HTML').append("<script id='myscript' src='/feeds/posts/default/-/Break?published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=one'><\/script>");

  });
});
```

[Live demo for the problem](http://test-khamsat-support-gig.blogspot.com/)

Comment: In jQuery there are about forty such methods.

Comment: @adeneo can you give some exemples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In raw javascript you can use `innerHTML` property of an element, e.g.:

```
var stringToAppend = "<script id='myscript' src='/feeds/posts/default/-/Break?published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=one'><\/script>";
document.getElemetsByClassName('HTML')[0].innerHTML += stringToAppend;
```

Notice that I used `+=` operator to **append** the string to already existing content.

`a += b` is the equivalent of `a = a + b`

---

If you are open to *jQuery* and simply want to append the content to the end of the page, call the `append` method on the `body` selector:

```
$('body').append('<a href="'+posturl+'">'+posttitle+'</a><h2>'+posttitle+'</h2>     <span>'+postAuthor+'</span><span>'+postLabels+'</span><div>'+img[i]+'</div>');
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you give me the first code with JQuery not JavaScript

Comment: You already have the first part of code in your question. I'm not sure if I got the point.

Comment: tha main idea is I want to add the script code that content id="myscript" with jquery to a div on the template. Can you help me with that.

Comment: Why do you want to add it to specific `div`? It doesn't make any difference for the page where you load a script. Anyway, you can do it the way you did it in your question. Take the whole line with `$('.HTML').append(...)` and replace the `.HTML` with `body`. You won't need anything else to load a script to the already rendered page.